# MySql Raw Query into Laravel 5.5 Eloquent ORM

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel-5, eloquent

I have mySql query an I want to convert it into Laravel 5.5 Eloquent ORM.

mySql Query:

```
SELECT i.category_id, count(i.id) as count FROM `items` i INNER JOIN item_categories c ON c.id = i.`category_id` GROUP BY i.`category_id`
```

This query is working. Is there any way to convert it easily into eloquent or anyone can make it for me.

Answer (score 1):

Using eloquent it will be like

```
$categories = Category::withCount('items')->get();
```

[Counting Related Models](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships)

Comment: @Moiz Post your model(items & category) definitions in your question, so that i can see how they are related with each other